# Need key placement help in the following loop along with conversion of one div element in React js

Tags: reactjs

I understand the concept of key in a loop on basic level.
But my html is such that I am getting confused.
Here's the loop I need help in placing the key at. `key=product.id`
ALso, if we have selected one of the div, how do we change it from bg-success to bg-primary?

```
   {products.map(product => (
                                <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div className="card rounded bg-success p-5 my-3 mr-3 text-center">
                                        <h4>{product.title}</h4>
                                        <h1 className="price">${product.price}</h1>
                                        <ul className="no-disk">
                                            <li key={product.id}>{product.month_count}</li>
                                            <li>{product.time} Package</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <img className="img-responsive " src="images/store.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
```

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple unrelated questions in the same question description.

Comment: The key in React is always set on the root element of the repeated item.

Comment: As for the classes, it's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: @EmileBergeron 
I read this question and understood the answer to some extend. I need syntax help in my question above. Its a straight forward syntax help that I am asking for

Comment: You've already used the right syntax here: `key={product.id}`, just put that on the first `div`. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be noted that React will advise against the method below due to what keys do for repeated React components.

When you bring in data of some sort, maybe make sure that each index has its own ID.

In any case, `map` is an Array method that allows you to get the index and the element at the index, so the below approach will work, but it should be used sparingly.

```
   {products.map((product,id) => (
                                <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div className="card rounded bg-success p-5 my-3 mr-3 text-center">
                                        <h4>{product.title}</h4>
                                        <h1 className="price">${product.price}</h1>
                                        <ul className="no-disk">
                                            <li key={product.id}>{product.month_count}</li>
                                            <li>{product.time} Package</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <img className="img-responsive " src="images/store.png" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
```

Comment: how do we check if one div is selected? then change it from bg-success to bg-primary? 
have to do it via react js, not via javascript

Comment: got it, the id is the index that you mentioned above!! 
used it for if else inside like  this :  index == '0' ? div of primary : div of success

Comment: This is something I would definitely use a hook for. React hooks allow us to hold state much closer to smaller components: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html